# Sharing a configuration file to multiple docker containers

Tags: linux, docker

Suppose I have the following configuration file on my Docker host, and I want multiple Docker containers to be able to access this file.

```
/opt/shared/config_file.yml
```

In a typical non-Docker environment I could use symbolic links, such that:

```
/opt/app1/config_file.yml -> /opt/shared/config_file.yml
/opt/app2/config_file.yml -> /opt/shared/config_file.yml
```

Now suppose app1 and app2 are dockerized.  I want to be able to update config_file.yml in one place and have all consumers (docker containers) pick up this change without requiring the container to be rebuilt.

I understand that symlinks cannot be used to access files on the host machine that are outside of the docker container.

The first two options that come to mind are:

1. Set up an NFS share from docker host to docker containers
2. Put the config file in a shared Docker volume, and use docker-compose to connect app1 and app2 to the shared config docker

I am trying to identify other options and then ultimately decide upon the best course of action.

Comment: Mounting the file as a volume is what you're looking for (see answer from @AndyShinn). To scale this out to multiple containers have you considering running a configuration a configuration store like consul or etcd? There are compatible template engines that will keep local files in the container up to date with configuration changes. See: https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd

Comment: Mark, thank you for the suggestion. Both consul and etcd look interesting. I think the service discovery/distributed config concept can solve a lot of these problems.

Comment: This is exactly my situation, although I need to share a "constant.js" file between microservices. Given that this question is 4 years old, did you find any other / better solution or do you think this is still relevant / recommended? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about host mounted volumes? If each application is only reading the configuration and the requirement is that it lives in different locations within the container you could do something like:

```
docker run --name app1 --volume /opt/shared/config_file.yml:/opt/app1/config_file.yml:ro app1image
docker run --name app2 --volume /opt/shared/config_file.yml:/opt/app2/config_file.yml:ro app2image
```

The file on the host can be mounted at a separate location per container. In Docker 1.9 you can actually have arbitrary volumes from specific plugins to hold the data (such as [Flocker](https://docs.clusterhq.com/en/1.8.0/introduction/flocker-plugin.html)). However, both of these solutions are still per host and the data isn't available on multiple hosts at the same time.

Comment: Andy, thank you for your answer. This solution works.  Also thank you for recommending Flocker. I am still figuring out the docker way of doing things.  Do you know if a multiple host solution can be achieved using Swarm?

Comment: I currently use NFS for multi-host file sharing. Swarm is just a scheduler AFAIK, it doesn't really tie in to NFS. With swarm, you will still need to bootstrap the NFS mount somehow.

I've been paying attention to storage solutions. But I haven't seen any for multi-host concurrent file mounting. All of them are mostly currently for persistence and the ability to move between hosts (*move* being the keyword).